# Check for empty string in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am learning Batch scripting and I copied example how to check for empty :

```
@echo off 
SET a= 
SET b=Hello 
if [%a%]==[] echo "String A is empty" 
if [%b%]==[] echo "String B is empty "
```

but I get such error:

```
D:\Projects\Temp\BatchLearning>Script.bat
]==[] was unexpected at this time.
```

what the problem? Why this was in guide. Did it work in past? Example from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_empty_string.htm).

**UPD:**

I deleted some whitespaces in the end of 2nd, 3rd and 5th(last) lines and everything works now as expected, what is going on?

Comment: `if "%a%"==""`, or even better, `if not defined a`

Comment: @aschipfl But why did that spaces destroyed my script?

Comment: The space is a token separator in CMD, which must be protected by surrounding `""`...

Comment: You should use the extended syntax of SET `set "a="` and `set "b=Hello"` to avoid trailing invisible spaces.See also the answer of Mofi. `set "<var>=<content>"` the quotes are not stored in the variable, but the last quote is the end mark for the content

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An environment variable cannot have an empty string. The environment variable is not defined at all on assigning nothing to an environment variable.

The help of command **IF** output on running in a command prompt window explains the syntax:

```
if defined Variable ...
if not defined Variable ...
```

This works as long as command extensions are enabled as by default on starting `cmd.exe` or running a batch file.

```
@echo off
SET "a="
SET "b=Hello"
if not defined a echo String A is empty.
if not defined b echo String B is empty.
```

The square brackets have no meaning for command **IF** or for Windows command processor. But double quotes have one as they define an argument string. So possible is also using:

```
@echo off
SET "a="
SET "b=Hello"
if "%a%" == "" echo String A is empty.
if "%b%" == "" echo String B is empty.
```

But please note that a double quote character `"` inside string value of `a` or `b` with expansion by command processor before execution of the parsed command line as done here with `%a%` and `%b%` results in a syntax error of the command line.

Read also answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) why it is recommended to use the syntax `set "Variable=Value"` to avoid getting assigned to an environment variable a value with not displayed trailing whitespaces.